# Booting on sdb redirects do Grub on sda

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

My computer have 2 HDDs, one SSD that has Ubuntu 20.10 and Windows 10 dual booting and one HD with Fedora, that I installed to start learning Red Hat Linux.

All was working well, until I decided to install Grub from Ubuntu on sdb using the commands

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
sudo update-grub
```

So I could boot into Fedora using my Grub on SSD

And now, when i try to boot to Fedora, the only thing that happens is that it redirects me to the Grub on sda, that is on my SSD.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Fedora. Did you install grub from Ubuntu or Fedora?

Comment: I installed it from Ubuntu, forgot to mention that

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 0):

It used the configuration of the `Ubuntu` to install it, You need to do a re-check when you install to have it find the `Fedora` not a simple install of what was there already. There are `UUIDs` that are used in the `GRUB` configuration files, those are what have you booting into the Ubuntu those `IDs` for it. If you want `Fedora's` `GRUB` on its `SSD` then see if you can boot the installer and re-install it without the Win/Ubuntu drive installed. This will eliminate them from the equation and once installed use the `F12` key, if my computer to get a boot menu, this will boot either drive as the first in the system. Then when their boot loaders like `GRUB` get updated they should do it correctly to the first drive in the system it thinks it has booted from. Since neither drive will know about the other, a simple `GRUB` install/update will not put the other OS in their menu as option to boot from.